# Do I cast the result of mkl_malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, casting, malloc, intel-mkl

Of course I know that we don't cast the result of `malloc()`, but what about `mkl_malloc()`?

Here is the [prototype](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522141): `void* mkl_malloc (size_t alloc_size, int alignment);`

It has the same return type as [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), as you can see: `void* malloc (size_t size);`

As a result, I would not cast the result, for these [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2411320). But the Intel people do, as you can see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522145), which makes me fear that I am missing something.

Does anybody know?

Comment: No, in C you don't need to cast *anything* returning `void *`. All pointers are implicitly convertible from and to `void *`.

Comment: Exactly @JoachimPileborg, but I am wondering if the Intel people have some other intention! That's why I asked and I think it would be good to get an answer, since I searched and found nothing.

Comment: If you check the prototype for `mkl_malloc` you see that is has some extra argument, right? That means it does *more* than just allocating a chunk of memory. And a `void *` is a `void *` no matter when or where it is.

Comment: Yes, it will align the memory @JoachimPileborg. I will agree. Should I wait for an answer so that a future user won't "waste" the same as me or delete the question?

Comment: There is a lot of code out there that has superfluous casts, but I don't think that this proves anything. People have habits (e.g they acquired when programming with another language such as C++). Sometimes these habits are bad, sometimes very bad. Cast are one of these, besides very specific, marginal use cases, good C code has no casts at all.

Comment: d'accord @JensGustedt, that's what I had in mind, that C++ did somehow affected the example, I think that your comment combined with Joachim's could serve as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting the result is superfluous and doesn't make much sense, so you shouldn't do it for that reason. But it is not super-important, it is a minor trifle.

The whole "cast the result of malloc" debate has gone out of proportion on Stack Overflow, and the most valid concerns of why you shouldn't went obsolete 16 years ago when implicit int was removed from the C language.

Comment: Does "implicit int" in the answer mean that before C99 the compiler assume malloc() returns an int when not including 'stdlib.h' to provide a prototype?

Comment: @Eli4ph Indeed, on ancient compilers it would be dangerous to forget about stdlib.h in combination with casting the result of malloc. This is what triggered this whole debate. But such old compilers shouldn't be used - if they are then the main concern should be "why do I use a stone age compiler for" rather than "why do I cast the result of malloc".